# How to find out master product of simple product?

Tags: php, magento

How can I find out, if a simple product is part of a configurable product and then get the master product? I need this for the product listing.

Just found out:

```
$_product->loadParentProductIds();
$parentIds = $_product->getParentProductIds();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that you have your simple product's Product ID.

To get all the parent configurable product IDs of this simple product, use the following code:-

```
<?php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_SIMPLE_PRODUCT_ID);
$parentIdArray = $_product->loadParentProductIds()
                 ->getData('parent_product_ids');
if(!empty($parentIdArray)) {
    // currently in the master configurable product
    print_r($parentIdArray); // this prints all the parent product IDs using your simple product.
}
?>
```

I suppose this should get you going.

Comment: Yeah, that is they way I've used.

Answer (score 4):

After version 1.4.2.0 the `loadParentProductIds()` and `getParentProductIds()` methods are deprecated. Don't ask me why. Personally I kind of liked those methods. So I've reintroduced them to my local Mage classes. This is how:
Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
```

and change the `loadParentProductIds()` method, found around line 1349 to:

```
public function loadParentProductIds()
{
        return $this->_getResource()->getParentProductIds($this);
}
```

This piece of code will query its resource for its parent product ids. For this to work we'll need to rewrite the `getParentProductIds()` method in the resource class.

So copy:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product.php
```

Find the deprecated `getParentProductIds()` method. Should be somewhere around line 535. Overwrite it with the pre 1.4.2.0 code:

```
public function getParentProductIds($object){
    $childId = $object->getId();
    $groupedProductsTable = $this->getTable('catalog/product_link');
    $groupedLinkTypeId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED;
    $configurableProductsTable = $this->getTable('catalog/product_super_link');

    $groupedSelect = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('g'=>$groupedProductsTable), 'g.product_id')
        ->where("g.linked_product_id = ?", $childId)
        ->where("link_type_id = ?", $groupedLinkTypeId);

    $groupedIds = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol($groupedSelect);

    $configurableSelect = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('c'=>$configurableProductsTable), 'c.parent_id')
        ->where("c.product_id = ?", $childId);

    $configurableIds = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol($configurableSelect);
    return array_merge($groupedIds, $configurableIds);
}
```

Now you once again can do this:

```
$_product->loadParentProductIds()->getData('parent_product_ids');
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 4):

For Magento 1.4.2 and above use the following method instead:

```
$configurable_product_model = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product_type_configurable’);
$parentIdArray = $configurable_product_model->getParentIdsByChild($simple_product_id);
```